# Design Storm topology to process and persist usage metrics of use on a web page

Tags: mongodb, apache-storm

We are working on web application, that has a feature to generate metrics based on how user is using the app. We are exploring to use Storm to process the user events and generate metrics.

The high level approach we are planning :

1. On client side (Browser), a Java script component to capture user events and post the event to server, and event message will be posted to RabbitMQ.
2. Storm spout consumes message from RabbitMQ.
3. Storm bolt process the message and computes metrics.
4. Finally metrics get saved to MongoDB

Question :

Bolt has to accumulate event's metrics before saving to MongoDB because of two reasons, need to avoid IO load on MongoDB and metrics logic has dependency on multiple events.  So we need to have intermittent persistence for Bolt, and not impacting performance.

How can we add temporary persistence within storm topology while we calculate statistics on the data pulled from RabbitMQ, and then save metrics to permanent persistence MongoDB, only on some interval or some other logical trigger.

Answer (score 2):

Please clarify if I don't fully answer your question but the general gist of your query seems to echo the theme: how can we persist within our storm topology while we calculate statistics on the data pulled from RabbitMQ?

Luckily for you, Storm has already considered this question and developed Storm-Trident, which performs real time aggregation on incoming tuples and allows the topology to persist the aggregated state for DRPC queries and for situations requiring high availability and persistence.

For example, in your particular scenario, you would have this kind of TridentTopology:

```
 TridentTopology topology = new TridentTopology();
 TridentState metricsState = topology.newSpout(new RabbitMQConsumer())
    .each(new Fields("rawData"), new ComputeMetricsFunction(), new Fields("output"))
    .groupBy(new Fields("output"))
    .persistentAggregate(new MemoryMapState.Factory(), new AggregatorOfYourChoice(), new Fields("aggregationResult"))
```

Note: the code isn't 100% accurate but should be considered more as pseudo-code. See Nathan's word count example for code specific implementation (https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki/Trident-tutorial).

Comment: Yes thats exactly my question. Storm-Trident, is it different than Trident ?  Is it possible to Storm-Trident to be a plugin to Storm ?

Comment: Trident is simply a higher level abstraction of the Bolt-Spout topology. It allows you to create more complicated topologies, such as the one you described, without having to worry about the higher level joining of bolts and spouts in order to persist state. Have a look at that link I sent you and it should become clearer to you.